# Phonegap/Cordova app pops up permission dialogs on Android when it's already in the manifest

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, phonegap-plugins

I'm having a problem with a Phonegap app I'm creating which uses location & camera. Whenever it's freshly installed and run (using "phonegap run android"), the app pops up a dialog saying "Allow [app] access to this device's location?" and in another part where the user selects an image from their gallery, it pops up saying "Allow access to storage?". How do I stop these dialogs? The permissions are already explicitly specified in the manifest so I don't get why it needs to ask.

The dialogs themselves however aren't the real problem. The real problem is **these permissions are getting denied even when the user presses "allow".** A secondary dialog appears after pressing allow that says "Screen overlay detected". It seems that whenever a permission is requested it's denied because some **other** app has an overlay permission. The problem here is the other app is Facebook Messenger, which everyone and their grandma uses, so telling everyone to turn off Messenger so my little app will work is not an option.

So how do I stop these permission dialogs from popping up? The permissions are already in the manifest. Is it possible this only appears during development? I hope so because I certainly can't ship like this.

I'm using Android 6.0.1.

Thank you!

Comment: Those permissions as shown by the system on Android 6 and greater and there is nothing you can do to avoid them. If an app is interfering with them, you should try to contact them, or even to google as this looks like a real bad bug on that app.